# Not getting distinct query results in Symfony 1.4 / Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I've got this query in my TurnoveroverVolumeTable class:

```
$query = $this->createQuery('tv')
        ->addSelect('DISTINCT tv.debtor_number')
        ->addSelect('tv.debtor_name')
        ->addSelect('tv.country_description')
        ->addSelect('SUM(tv.turnover_ytd) as tv.turnover_ytd')
        ->addSelect('tv.currency_description')
        ->from('TurnoverVolume tv')
            ->innerJoin('tv.Agent a')
            ->andWhere('tv.debtor_number = a.debtor_number')
            ->andWhere('a.agent_number =?', $agent)
            ->andWhere('tv.period LIKE "' . $year .'%"')
            ->groupBy('tv.debtor_number');
```

When retrieving and displaying the data I use this in my actions class:

```
$query = Doctrine_Core::getTable('TurnoverVolume')->getYearTurnover($agent_number, $this->currentYear);

$results = $query->execute();

        $turnover_data = array();
        foreach ($results as $turnover) {
            $turnover_result = array(
                'debtor_number' => $turnover['debtor_number'],
                'debtor_name' => $turnover['debtor_name'],
                'country_description' => $turnover['country_description'],
                'turnover_ytd' => $turnover['turnover_ytd'],
                'currency_description' => $turnover['currency_description']
            );
            $turnover_data[] = $turnover_result;
        }
```

The result I'm getting for turnover_ytd is 2703 but should be 277450, it only gets the first result of the year 2011 and not the total result of the year 2011.

In the logs of Symfony I have this MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.company_number AS t__company_number, t.debtor_number AS t__debtor_number, t.period AS t__period, t.debtor_name AS t__debtor_name, t.country_description AS t__country_description, t.currency_description AS t__currency_description, SUM(t.turnover_ytd) AS t__0 FROM turnover_volume t INNER JOIN agent a ON t.debtor_number = a.debtor_number WHERE (t.debtor_number = a.debtor_number AND a.agent_number = '003' AND t.period LIKE "2011%") GROUP BY t.debtor_number
```

Which gets me the right result, when I enter it directly into the MySQL database.

Can anyone expain to me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

> DISTINCT must be capitalized
>   'as' must be used, without this everything will be returned
>   use fetchArray() instead of execute(), the latter doesn't work!

[source](http://www.prettyscripts.com/framework/symfony/symfony-and-doctrine-select-distinct-column)